# How to share a general state when using CombineReducers with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm really new to Redux and I want to share a question regarding how I should implement this.

I do have a full application written in React, where each page represents a single React component.
Each React component does have it's own Redux Reducer and actions.

Let's take a very simple example, a `HomePage` component.

```
class HomePage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Home Page</h1>
        )
    }
}
```

I do have a reducer which modifies the current state indicating the application has been completely bootstrapped.

```
export default function homePageReducer(state = {appBootstrapped: false}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'APP_BOOTSTRAPPED':
            state = { appBootstrapped: true }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

The Redux action is the following:

```
export function SetApplicationBootstrapped() {
    return { type: 'APP_BOOTSTRAPPED' }
}
```

My component is adapted to use the Redux implementation above:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        homePage: state.homePageReducer
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomePage);
```

Now, from within my component, I can call my action to inform React that my application has been completely bootstrapped.
However, it doesn't feel right, because if I have 10 pages, each represented by a component, and each component does have it's own reducer/actions, I need to implement the call to bootstrap the application in every reducer?

Is this the normal Redux approach?

If not, how should I handle this?

The basic idea is that I want to have a component, representing a loading screen which I would like to hide as soon as the application is bootstrapped.
But since each component has only access to it's own actions, I cannot change the state of another component. I'm a bit lost with the idea of 'shared' state since to me it seems that, even with combineReducers, each reducer manage it's own state, not allowing to access the state of another reducer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you limit that *each component can only access its own reducer and actions*. In your case I think you can still have a shared state, for example

```
{
  shared: { ... },
  pageA: { ... },
  pageB: { ... },
  pageC: { ... }
}
```

so now you can put `appBootstrapped` in `shared`, and create a shared action for that.

---

You just need to create a top level component, so you can only dispatch `SetApplicationBootstrapped` once.

Also, you shouldn't mutate the state in your reducer:

```
case 'APP_BOOTSTRAPPED':
    state = { appBootstrapped: true }
```

just return the state object right in the case statement

```
case 'APP_BOOTSTRAPPED':
    return { appBootstrapped: true }
```

Comment: I think there's a small misunderstanding here. Each page (component), will have some logic before rendering such as fetching data from an API. Each page will execute another API call. Only when the API call is finished, I want to dispatch the action setting that the application has been bootstrapped. I don't see how that can be done using a `top-level-component`. So, how can I, from each component, set the state that my application is bootstrapped without implementing a loading screen in each component? So component X must change state that allows the re-render of component Y.

Comment: I can easily solve this problem by only using a single reducer. That way I do only have one single state, but I'm wondering if this is the correct approach.

Comment: Thanks for the update, does this mean that in `mapStateToProps`, each component must have access to the `Shared` state, and call the action to hide the loading screen?

Comment: Yes, I don't know the structure of your project, maybe create another folder for the shared things, and the components import it